# Zapf Chancery and placing a k next to a g

Tags: fonts, kerning

So, I was playing with fonts and found one really nice. It's just that I ran into trouble trying to write the word Background (quite a common word, eh?) using it. The k and the g extend into each other. And if I add space between them I have to add very much space indeed. (actually way too much) Are there more variants of the characters hidden somewhere or is this a case of broken-by-design? (It can't be, can it?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LARGE \fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont Background
\end{document}
```

[image: k and g]

Comment: I added a picture of the problem. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is by design and not considered broken by the designer. It's unusual indeed, but I also wouldn't consider it as broken.

Comment: I tried selecting alternate glyph variants using `fontspec` and the OTF version of TeX Gyre Chorus (a font based on Chancery), but to no avail, so @Hendrik might as well be right. The only difference I get is that the characters are kerned to not to overlap, just like in Seamus's example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might prefer the way the [`tgchorus`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgchorus/) font does this. It is based on chancery. I'm not sure it's any better really. The realy best option would be proper ligatures. But for a script font like these, you'd need *a lot* of ligatures...

[image: tgchorus]

#### Edit

So I recently found [this article](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/ftp/techreports/TR136.pdf) by Douglas Hofstadter about metafont (among other things) and on p.42 (figure 14) at the bottom there is all the Zapf Chancery glyphs. These include, among others, a "K" without the fancy tail. I wonder if this is in the TeX version of the font. Because if so, then it's exactly what you'd need. I don't know how to access the alternative versions though... I wonder if there is a mechanism like `\varphi` for normal letters...

#### Edit 2

Having [worked out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18218/215) how to print the font table of Zapf Chancery, it looks like it doesn't contain the less swishy "K". Nor does tgchorus...

Comment: Okey, I guess I will just have to move on to some other font then...

Comment: FWIW, I find Zapf Chancery's "Background" prettier than this `tgchorus` above. I don't see anything wrong with Chancery's "Background" either.

Comment: @Seamus: glad to hear this actually was not a case of broken-by-design at least.

Comment: I spent some more time looking at this. Seems the Zapf Chancery in LaTeX is based on the italic version. What was in that article was not an italic version. So there is still the question whether there ever was such a k in the italic version of the font I guess...

Comment: @jonalv I guess if you could find the full font metric files there might be a chance to get upright version with non-swishy K through XeTeX?

Comment: @Seamus: If I could get the full font file (with that other k version) things would indeed be good. In fact I found the non-italic version of the font as true type on the web and I am using that now instead...