# Making a fonttable of Zapf Chancery

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use [fonttable](http://ctan.org/pkg/fonttable) to make a table of the Zapf Chancery font (in order to improve my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/zapf-chancery-and-placing-a-k-next-to-a-g)).

The following document compiles fine and looks right: the font is being used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont Lorem Ipsum
%\fonttable{pzc}
\end{document}
```

However, when I uncomment the `\fonttable` line, I get errors:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm pzc
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzc
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf pzc
! I can't find file `pzc'.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzc

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzc

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: pzc.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pzc' failed to make pzc.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font \f@ttestfont=pzc not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \f@ttestfont 
l.5 \fonttable{pzc}

[1{/home/seamus/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./chanceryfonttable.aux) )
```

What can I do to get my font table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\fonttable` command wants the name of the `tfm` file, something like `pzcmi7t`. There is `\xfonttable` that requires four arguments

```
\xfonttable{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

so you should write, for example,

```
\xfonttable{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

If you insist on `\fonttable`, you can write

```
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
\expandafter\fonttable\expandafter{\fontname\font}
```

since `\fontname\font` expands to the `tfm` file name of the current font.

Comment: How can I find the name of the `tfm` file? I searched the log file for `tfm` and got no useful hits...

Comment: @Seamus: That's why I suggested Peter Wilson to add `\xfonttable`. :) You have to examine the `.fd` file relative to the family you're interested in. In this case `ot1pzc.fd`, or `t1pzc.fd`, or `ts1pzc.fd`, for the various encodings. I'll add another trick in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The fonttable package doesn't do what you want to achieve. It doesn't show the complete glyph pool of a font. It will show you the glyph encoded and requested by the tfm/enc-combination you used.

e.g. try this and then again without the `<8r.enc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV12]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\pdfmapline{=pzcmi8r URWChanceryL-MediItal <8r.enc <uzcmi8a.pfb}
\begin{document}

\fonttable{pzcmi8r}
\end{document}
```

A type1 font can also contain glyph not used by any tex/tfm-font.

You must look at the font with a fontviewer like fontforge (doesn't work for me with the urw zapf chancery) or look in the afm-file. E.g.  `uzcmi8a.afm` shows this glyph (`Kcommaaccent`)

`C -1 ; WX 660 ; N Kcommaaccent ; B 88 -270 851 577 ;`

To see how it looks, make a copy of 8r.enc e.g. called 8rtest.enc in the current folder, and change the /K in the file to `/Kcommaaccent` then try the example above again with `8rtest.enc`.

Btw: I can't see any name in afm which sounds like "non swashy K". So I don't think that the urw zapf chancery contains the glyph.